# Number of days between dates?

Tags: datediff, reportbuilder3.0

Dipping my toe into the world of reporting.  I'm using Report Builder 3.0 and what I'm trying to do seems really easy, but I can't get it to work...  I've got 2 datetime2 columns StartDate and EndDate and I want I'm trying to do is work out how many days are between them and if it more than 100 then display true otherwise display false.  I've tried:

```
=IIF(DateDiff("Day",Fields!StartDate.value,Fields!EndDate.value)>100,True, False)
```

Or

```
=IIF(Fields!EndDate.value - Fields!StartDate.value > 100, True, False)
```

Even just getting it to return the number of days:

```
=DateDiff("Day",Fields!StartDate.value,Fields!EndDate.value)
```

And all 3 of them give me #Error.  Does anyone have a clue where I'm going wrong or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being stupid and have worked it out...  The expression should have looked like this:

```
=IIF(DateDiff("d",Fields!StartDate.value,Fields!EndDate.value)>1,True,False)
```